# UEFI boot options gone

Tags: uefi

I ran into some issues booting Windows after trying to make a complete backup of the disc. After searching for information about some of the error codes, I found advise to change some BIOS settings, but instead I thought I would just "restore defaults" to make sure all settings were set as originally intended.

After doing so, all UEFI boot options except for "Windows Boot Manager" are gone. That means, including the CD/DVD drive, so I cannot even boot from a recovery DVD anymore - and as explained, Windows is not able to boot either.

Do you have any advice?

When I added a secondary drive originally, it was automatically added to the boot options menu. Even when removing and re-adding the drive physically, the option does not appear again. I have tried unplugging power, and hold down start button for 10 seconds, and boot afterwards - no change. It's a laptop so removing CMOS battery is not an option.

I have read information that it is an issue with data removed from NVRAM, but I am unable to find a way to recover it. "Add new boot options" requires a path - but the CD/DVD was originally available without any CD's in the drive - so there is no path available to add the drive.

I did try to open EFI shell, but it seems not to be embedded in the UEFI/BIOS. It just says "not found".

I'm really lost here - any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Good walkthrough at http://scienceblogs.com/aardvarchaeology/2013/12/16/tech-note-how-to-install-linux-on-a-laptop-with-uefi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution (problem occured 2 days ago) :)
I was quite sure that I had tried all possible settings in BIOS (UEFI), but it turns out that a bad combination caused some settings to revert after each reboot.

First I disabled Secure Boot Control.
Then I enabled "Launch CSM" and "Launch PXE OpROM".

I checked with the demo-machine in the store, and these settings match. The Asus boot logo is back, and all boot options are back :)